# File Structure / Directory View in Drupal

Tags: drupal

Is there a way to have some sort of file structure or Directory view in Drupal? I've been searching for a couple weeks but haven't found anything.

EDIT: I am wanting some sort of file organization for every webpage in the content view (admin level), I want to be able to have folders and subfolders, that would essentially look publicly like www.example.com/folder/another_folder/file.html

Comment: Please add more information, there is many ways to organize file directories on drupal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a file browser/manage for your user, one of the more popular ones is [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce).

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.

Check out the related projects on the [IMCE page](http://drupal.org/project/imce) to see other similar modules.